# Conditionally registering users

Tags: user-registration

I have a WP website, that needs to create an account via API call in another service. So whenever a user registers in this website, i need to call an API in this other website too.

I added a hook to `user_register` and it works - the problem is if that's any error in the game account creationg the user will still be in WP, for instance if the password breaks the other service validation etc.

Here's a shortened version of what im doing:

```
add_action( 'user_register', function ( $user_id ) {
     $result = create_game_account($_POST["signup_username"], $_POST["signup_password"], $user_id);
     $cod = explode(':',$result,5)[0];
     if($cod!=3) {
      error_log("Error creating game account");
      require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/user.php');
      wp_delete_user($user_id);
    } 
});
```

However this not only sometimes generates a infinite loading but also does not delete the user from database.

Any ideas how can this be solved ?